# Fifty Shades Darker, 'Code Blue' song by The Dream

Tags: lyrics, meaning, soundtrack, song-title

From the movie 'Fifty Shades Darker' a song by **The Dream** which is **'Code Blue'** has these repeated lines.

> That's what I get for loving you, code blue 
>   That's what I get for loving you, code blue

As far as I've learned **Code Blue** is-

> Code Blue (emergency code), a hospital code used to indicate a patient
>    requiring immediate resuscitation.

1. Why does he get code blue? Is the separation making him feel like he's dead?
2. But then, when she was with him was loving her also code blue then? As he only says **that's what he got from loving her.**
3. Why does he feel like crying when he is close to her?

   > The closer I get to you; The more I feel like crying.

I'd appreciate any help as googling didn't help much. I'd like to get somebody's point of view or maybe a succinct clarification.

[Link to the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blmOl_PeaMU).
[Link to the lyrics](https://genius.com/The-dream-code-blue-lyrics).

Comment: when does this song appear in the movie? i can’t remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, when his lover is away he feels like dying by heart arrest, so he is warning "Code Blue" so the lover comes back to make his heart live again.
2. The fact that he falled in love induced the heartache when she's gone. "That's what I get for loving you" sort of means he contracted this sickness that requires a "Code Blue" anytime she's away.
3. This might be related to the movie issue of S&M love, which includes love with physical pain. That is maybe why he cries. He could also cry because when he is with the lover, he know it won't last and the lover will leave him again.

Answer (score 0):

Well the 'code blue' is hospital emergency short code that is used when someone has a heart attack. And he loves her so much but she doesn't love him back and it gives him pain in heart, and she doesn't even care about his love and hurts him, that's why he says he feels like crying when getting close to her. It's like a lose-lose situation for him, both ways he has pain, because he knows she doesn't love him, and he won't get that love, just pain in his heart or code blue.

Answer (score 0):

Red is the safe word...which means stop in the movie...and code blue means it's ok...and that's what he gets for actually showing her love she wanted and needed from him...he gets to do his red room Stuff on her...

Answer (score -1):

These tears are tears of joy because she is close to him, loving him and sharing his breath. In the opposite, when she is far and he can't reach her, his heart beat stops.

Answer (score -1):

This song may not mean to the artist the same thing it does to me but I feel it describes me. There are things about my relationship with my wife that make me sad (want to cry) when we are close. But being away from her is worse (wanting to die).  I think this song is about a love that regardless if you stay or go it will stop your heart (code blue)